# laravel migration creates different schema

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I was watching a tutorial from [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/lessons/laravel-installation-for-newbs) titles "Laracast Digging In" and the first part illustrates how to use eloquent simply by doing.

```
# app/models/tasks.php
class tasks extends Eloquent{

}
```

then goes on to do
 `php artisan migration:make create_tasks_table --create --table="tasks"`

Then a migration file is made that looks like this.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTasksTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create("tasks", function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments("id"); 
                        $table->timestamps(); 
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop("tasks");
    }

}
```

#### While I do exactly the same, I am getting slightly a different result.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTasksTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('tasks', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            //
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('tasks', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            //
        });
    }

}
```

As you can see, aside my approach omitting

```
$table->increments("id"); 
$table->timestamps();
```

It has entirely replaced `create` with `table` here.

```
Schema::table('tasks', function(Blueprint $table)
        ^^ is 'create' in the tutorial.
```

Why, is this happening. If I simply ignore this and start following the tutorial I can't get anything to work. And I don't want to modify this by hand, so why is this happening and how do I solve it.

Comment: when you do it yourself, does the table already exists?

Comment: When I do it. A table called `migrations` gets created. and inside it, there are rows called `migrations` and `batch`. But no sign of table called `tasks`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the command wrong

Based on [Laravel tutorial](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#creating-migrations)
use this :

**For creating a table**

```
php artisan migrate:make create_tasks_table --create=tasks
```

**For updating a table**

```
php artisan migrate:make create_tasks_table --table=tasks
```

Basically you need to use `--create` OR `--table` not both.
when you are using `--create` , then the migration will be with `Schema::create` indicating that the migration will create a table

when you are using `--table` , then the  migration will be `Schema::table` indicating that a table will be updated

Comment: Did you mean `migrate:make` ?

Comment: Thanks. Got it solved. But as you [can see in this image](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2eatcok.jpg) the tutorial used both flags. I don't understand how that worked out.

Comment: not sure exactly, maybe it's a mistake but based on the documentation,that command can't possibly create the desired outcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Use either `--table="tableName"` (Schema::table) for updating your table or `--create="tableName"` (Schema::create) for creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure in the tutorial you followed, the developper used
JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators.
utill you feel confortable with Laravel4, ignore the generator and replace 'table' by create or drop according to the action you want to execute.

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: I am pretty sure he was using the same commands as I was trying. I don't understand the problem. But, omitting `--table` did the job.